# Several threads in the same lock

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a thread-safe wrapper for a regular Queue class. But it seems that several threads may acquire the same lock. So my questions are:
 1. How it could be?
 2. How to avoid it?
 3. Any useful advice are pleased

This is my queue:

```
public class SafeQueue<T> : SimpleQueue<T>
{
    private readonly object sync = new object();
    private readonly Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

    public override T Dequeue()
    {
        T item;
        lock (sync)
        {
            Debug.Print("{1:mm ss ffff} {0} locked in dequeue", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
            item = queue.Dequeue();
        }
        Debug.Print("{1:mm ss ffff} {0} unlocked dequeue", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
        return item;

    }

    public override void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            queue.Enqueue( item );
        }
    }

    public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Queue<T> q;
        lock (sync)
        {
            q = new Queue<T>(queue);
        }

        return ((IEnumerable<T>) q).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int c;
            lock (sync)
            {
                Debug.Print("{1:mm ss ffff} {0} locked in count", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now);
                c = queue.Count;
            }
            Debug.Print("{1:mm ss ffff} {0} unlocked count. Ret {2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, DateTime.Now,c);
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a piece from where I use it (Work is a thread function):

```
private readonly SafeQueue<string> taskQueue = new SafeQueue<string>();
private volatile bool stop = false;
...
 private void Work()
    {
        while ( !stop )
        {
            string dir = null;
            if (taskQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                dir = taskQueue.Dequeue();
            }
...
```

So, the problem basically is: two threads are acquire the lock on Count property and return a positive value. Since that they both try to dequeue an element.

Comment: Two different threads can't enter the same lock EVER.  Something else is happening.  Also, what @CodesInChaos said.

Comment: if it is a .net 4, there's ConcurentQueue (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181410/Thread-safe-Collections-in-NET-4-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious bug is that an item might be dequeue between you checking the count, and the associated `Dequeue`. For this reason threadsafe queues typically have an atomic `TryDequeue` operations.

With such an operation, your code becomes:

```
while ( !stop )
{
    string dir;
    if(taskQueue.TryDequeue(out dir))
    {
    }
```

Your debug prints can be misleading too. You only print the "unlocked" line some time after the actual unlock occurs. So between the actual unlock and your debug output a different thread might enter the lock and print its "locked" line, leading to confusing output.

.net has two built in thread safe queues: `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which is non blocking, `BlockingCollection<T>` which is blocking.

Comment: This is a really obvious bug! Now I see. Thanks